# Touchmove event in Angular 2

Tags: angular

How can I use touch events such as `touchmove` in Angular 2+ (not gestures)? There sould be a directive

`(touchmove)="myMove()"`?

Hammer.js supports gestures but not the raw events?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes `touchmove` is a directive that lets you handle touch events

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cqc6rc)**

use chrome DevTool to simulate touch  event
[image]

Comment: can I listen this as global event? e.g. with `document.addEventListener`